# outlets renaming themselves? breaking geocodeAddressString()?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

## Environment:

- Xcode-8
- iOS-10
- Swift-3

## Overview:

  I've got what, to me, is a bizarre issue with respect to
  **Outlets**
  , which seem to change the name of their target when being setup and, I believe, is the source of the problems I'm having with
  `geocodeAddressString()`

## A Bit Of Backstory:

- My view has a number of elements, but for the purposes of this posting, I'm primarily concerned about the `UITextField`'s and how I believe they are affecting my `MKMapView` code (based somewhat on comments I saw here)

    [image]
- My `UITextField`'s are utilizing a slightly modified form of an *extension* (originally by 'nhgrif') which I found here where the aim is to be able to setup a daisy-chain of textfields such that hitting the <kbd>Next</kbd> (or <kbd>Return</kbd>) button on the pop-up keyboard will automatically proceed to the desired next (or in some cases, previous) textfield.

```
private var kAssociationKeyNextField:     UInt8 = 0
private var kAssociationKeyPreviousField: UInt8 = 1 // I added this

extension UITextField {
    @IBOutlet var nextField: UITextField? {
        get { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kAssociationKeyNextField) as? UITextField }
        set(newField) { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kAssociationKeyNextField, newField, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN) }
    }
    // I added the following
    @IBOutlet var previousField: UITextField? {
        get { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kAssociationKeyPreviousField) as? UITextField }
        set(newField) { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kAssociationKeyPreviousField, newField, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN) }
    }
}
```

From the Xcode / Storyboard perspective, this provides the following UI's for setting the next (and/or previous) field in the daisy-chain:

  [image]

## Drilling down

  I'm not sure how to really explain the issue I'm seeing other than with a screen-capture video, but since I cannot figure out how to post such here, a bunch of screenshots will have to do...
  - Start with the ***Name*** field, and set the `nextField` to ***Address***:

      [image]
  - Then select the ***Address*** field and set the `previousField` to ***Name*** and the `nextField` to ***City***:

      [image]

    So far, everything seems to be working fine...
  - Now select the ***City*** field and set the `previousField` to ***Address*** and the `nextField` to ***State***:

      [image]

    **Yikes!** Note that the name associated with the ***State*** field is now "***Next Field***"
  - Continue with the ***State*** field, setting the `previousField` to ***City*** and `nextField` to ***Zipcode***:

      [image]

    The ***State*** field still shows up as "***Next Field***" - and now the ***Zipcode*** field *ALSO* shows up as "***Next Field***"
  - Finish with the ***Zipcode*** field, setting the `previousField` to ***State*** - intentionally leaving the `nextField` unset:

      [image]

### Some More Code

  Here is
  *most*
  of the rest of this particular view class's code

```
class NewLocationViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var doGeoLocate: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var name:        UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var address:     UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var city:        UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var state:       UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var zipcode:     UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var done:        UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var map:         MKMapView!

    var coords:          CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        name.delegate    = self
        address.delegate = self
        city.delegate    = self
        state.delegate   = self
        zipcode.delegate = self

        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.delegate        = self
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
        currentLocation  = nil
        doGeoLocate.isOn = false
        map.isHidden     = true
        done.isEnabled   = false

        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden       = false
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if doGeoLocate.isOn == true {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        else if textField.nextField == nil {
            if (!checkFields()) {
                // walk back up chain to find last non-filled text-field...
                var tmpField = textField
                while ((tmpField.previousField != nil) && (tmpField.previousField?.hasText)!) {
                    tmpField = tmpField.previousField!
                }
                tmpField.previousField?.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
            else {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
        else {
            textField.nextField?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        return checkFields()
    }

    func checkFields() -> Bool {
        //... if doGeoLocate switch is on - return true
        //... if ALL fields are populated, call geocodeAddress() and return true
        //... otherwise return false
    }

    func geocodeAddress() {
        print("GA") //#=#
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        let addr     = "\(address.text) \(city.text) \(state.text) \(zipcode.text)"
        print("ADDR: `\(addr)'")//#=#
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(addr, completionHandler: {
            (placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            print("IN geocodeAddressString")//#=#
            //if error.localizedDescription.isEmpty == false {
            //    print("Geocode failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            //}
            //else if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                let placemark      = placemarks![0]
                let location       = placemark.location
                self.coords        = location!.coordinate
                self.map.isHidden  = false
            //}
        } as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)    //<<<=== NOTE THIS LINE
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        //...
    }

    @IBAction func toggleGeoLocate(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        //...
    }

    @IBAction func useNewLocation(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Upon running the app, filling in all the fields, when I click on the 'Done' button in the number-keypad associated with the Zipcode field - I get an exception.  The debugging log looks like this:

```
TFSR: (TFSR Optional("Name") => Optional("Address"))
    Returning false
TFSR: (TFSR Optional("Address") => Optional("City"))
    Returning false
TFSR: (TFSR Optional("City") => Optional("State"))
    Returning false
TFSR: (TFSR Optional("State") => Optional("Zipcode"))
    Returning false
GA
ADDR: `Optional("2112 Murray Avenue ") Optional("Pittsburgh ") Optional("PA") Optional("15217")'
(lldb)
```

The exception shows up as:

```
    func geocodeAddress() {
        //...
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(addr, completionHandler: {
            (placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            //...
        } as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)    //<<< Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10006c518)
    }
```

And yes, I verified that I have no breakpoints set in the code

## Summation

I'm reasonably sure that the `geocodeAddressString()` code is correct (I used it in another app for Swift-2), but I'm very suspicious of the way the State and Zipcode **Outlets** get renamed when I attempt to chain them with the other fields.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: As you say, it's unrelated - but what variables are you talking about? Are not variables camel-cased beginning with lower-case letters, the same as function names? Or are variables supposed to be all-lower-cases (with underscores?) - and then how does this relate to properties of an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest getting rid of those various casts:

```
func geocodeAddress() {
    //...
    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(addr) { placemarks, error in
        //...
    }
}
```

It's easiest to let it infer the correct types for you.

---

Regarding the naming of outlets, IB is trying to make life easier for you, naming them for you in the absence of any specified name. But with these additional outlets, its default algorithm is falling short. You can probably get around this by naming the outlets yourself in the "Document" section of the "Identity Inspector".

Comment: Wow!  That seems to have fixed the crashing issue (**Thanks!!**), though I still don't understand why the setting up of the outlets renames the targets.
I'll update the original post with the new code

Comment: Hmm - I was *going* to edit the post, but in so doing it looked like it broke the formatting, so suffice it to say, I did what you suggested

Comment: Regarding the naming of outlets, IB is trying to make life easier for you, naming them for you in the absence of any specified name. But with these additional outlets, it's default algorithm is falling short. You can probably get around this by naming the outlets yourself in the "Document" section of the "Identity Inspector".

Comment: BINGO - If I could give you 2 votes on this answer I would.  Strange that it gets confused, but nice to know that I can fix it myself (easily)